# limit of a sequence $u_n = (3+\sqrt{5} )^n -(3-\sqrt{5} )^n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-theorem

I would like to know the limit of the sequence:
$u_n = (3+\sqrt{5} )^n -(3-\sqrt{5} )^n$.

I tried to involve the binomial theorem but didn't find the answer

Comment: It's $\infty$ as second term goes to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
u_n = \underbrace{a^n}_{\to\infty} - \underbrace{b^n}_{\to 0}
$$
with $a > 1$ and  $0 < b < 1$,
so
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = \infty
$$

Comment: You need to write $a>1$ instead of $|a|>1$.

Answer (score 0):

$a>1>b>0 \implies a^n-b^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ ,since $b^n \to 0$

Comment: This shows that limit if exists must be $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks, I  made an unfortunate approximation error.

Comment: Your recurrence shows that if $a_{n} $ tends to a limit then the limit must be $0$. But this is not possible as $a_{n} \geq 1$. So $a_n$ does not have a finite limit. But to deduce that it tends to $\infty$ we must show that it is increasing. The second part of your answer (using $a, b$) is correct and depends on the fact that $a^{n} \to \infty$ if $a>1$. In fact the answer depends only on this fact.